# mongodb: how to write $or clause with RE

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to select all the records that whether the title contains keywords or the location contains the keywords:

```
name_regex = ".*" + keyword + ".*";
name_reg = re.compile(name_regex,re.IGNORECASE)
search_dict["title"] = name_reg
search_dict["location"] = name_reg
records = collection.find(search_dict)
```

This is going to find the $and clause. How to specify the $or clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pymongo equivalent of :

```
db.collection.find({$or:[{title:name_reg}, {location:name_reg}]})
```